Configuring Xdebug (PhpStorm docker) for scripts running in the background
Project stack: PHP 7.1 in Ubuntu image, Xdebug 2 and docker.
Architectural solution: a PHP script (server.php) is run on the server with this script:
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -x

pid=0

# SIGUSR1-handler
my_handler() {
  echo "my_handler"
}

# SIGTERM-handler
term_handler() {
  if [ $pid -ne 0 ]; then
    kill -SIGTERM "$pid"
    wait "$pid"
  fi
  exit 143; # 128 + 15 -- SIGTERM
}

# setup handlers
# on callback, kill the last background process, which is `tail -f /dev/null` and execute the specified handler
trap 'kill ${!}; my_handler' SIGUSR1
trap 'kill ${!}; term_handler' SIGTERM

# run application
#sudo /etc/init.d/datadog-agent start
service pgbouncer start
service blackfire-agent start
php /opt/userapi-app/app/server.php &

pid="$!"

# wait indefinitely
while true
do
  tail -f /dev/null & wait ${!}
done

Inside the server.php waits for messages from RabbitMQ and if there is one executes the Symfony application:
$workers = 0;
while (true) {
    $pid = pcntl_fork();
    if ($pid == -1) {
        die("could not fork");
    } else if ($pid) {
        $appstate = \Phalcon\Di::getDefault()->get('app.state');
        if (!$appstate->isWork()) {
            $appstate->setWork(true);
            registerSigHandlers();
        }

        $workers++;
        if ($workers >= $POOL) {
            pcntl_wait($status);
            $workers--;
        }
    } else {
        $appstate = \Phalcon\Di::getDefault()->get('app.state');
        $appstate->setWork(false);
        registerSigHandlers();
        $amqp();
        exit(1);
    }

    $appstate = \Phalcon\Di::getDefault()->get('app.state');
    if ($appstate->isTerminated()) {
        for ($i=0; $i<$workers; $i++) {
            pcntl_wait($status);
        }

        break;
    }
}

NOTE: please don't write about architectural solutions. I didn't develop them, my task is to configure Xdebug.
Xdebug is inside the container, PhpStorm configuration all configured.
ATTENTION: When restarting containers debugger starts and stops at breakpoints, that is working as it should.
The problem is that if you disable the Xdebug listener that was running during the start of the container and enable it again, it does not work, it does not debug the same breakpoints, although the server and Xdebug are running and working inside the container, it can be seen in the logs.
Spent a lot of time and broke my head why this is.
Max simultaneous connections is set to the maximum number: 20, doesn't help.
My xdebug.ini
zend_extension=xdebug.so
xdebug.mode=debug
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
xdebug.idekey=PHPSTORM
xdebug.remote_host=host.docker.internal
xdebug.remote_connect_back=0
xdebug.remote_port=9003
xdebug.remote_log=/opt/userapi-app/tmp/xdebug.log
xdebug.log_level=0

docker compose php config
  userapi-server-php:
    image: userapi_prod:prod
    build:
      context: ./
    extra_hosts:
      - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
     IDE_KEY: PHPSTORM
     XDEBUG_CONFIG: "remote_enable=1 remote_host=host.docker.internal remote_port=9003 remote_autostart=1 remote_connect_back=0"
     XDEBUG_MODES: debug
    command: /run/start_phpserver.sh
    volumes:
      - ./:/opt/userapi-app



As about why it doesn't work... If you set Xdebug directives in Docker settings, they only take effect when you load the container. Further changes are ignored.

@Álvaro González
nothing changes after starting the contenter
If you go into the container and make php server.php, debbagir will see everything and work fine.
It doesn't work (doesn't listen) when the script is in the background, either it doesn't have time to grab in the loop or the channels are overflowing I don't know.

I'm a bit confused / trying to understand what exactly is running there and what you are trying to debug. Can you please explain it a bit better? As I understand you have a server.php and you want to debug THAT script (or some another?). And that server.php is run in the background loop all the time (from when container starts until it getting shutdown). Or you are trying to debug some another script (that gets somehow called by that server.php (how exactly)?

You see, Xdebug tries to connect to a debug client (PhpStorm in your case) at the start of the script execution/request. So I'm thinking: if you are trying to debug something that is already running all the time, and PhpStorm was not listing when the container started, then Xdebug can see that "nobody listens". Anyway -- try using xdebug_break(); in place of a breakpoint -- will it do any better?

@LazyOne it takes a long time to unfold it's already boring me! I'll write back later, thanks! Yes you understood everything correctly in the first comment, that's how it works, what is executed in server.php is not important, it does not do anything if you enable listening already on the running container and does everything as it should if you listen when starting the container.

@LazyOne although I'll explain a bit - server.php listens to the rabbitmq queue and if there are messages for it, it starts the symfony application
xdebug_break() - I've never used this and would like it to work like a normal debugger and not in manual mode.

TBH tat did not make it more clear. "and if there are messages for it, it starts the symfony application" How does it start it? Executes another process? makes a class instance/calls a method on existing class in the same script? The code you have provided does not show that, hence I'm trying to get how it works. Because as I have said: Xdebug will not try to connect again if first attempt failed.

Another point: The debug client (PhpStorm in your case) tells Xdebug to set breakpoints when Xdebug communicates with a client. Only during those moments. Xdebug cannot set or unset breakpoint during normal runtime when it does not talk to the client (e.g. during endless loop). Remember: It's Xdebug that talks to a client (initiates the activity) and not other way around. If Xdebug sees no "debug me now" flag, it just does not interfere in PHP executing the code.
